# Query to capture TOP X% of the values based on subset aggregation

Tags: sql, r, subset, aggregation

Here is the table

```
parcel| packet|a |b | c
1     | p1    |20|40|50     
1     | p2    |20|90|50     
1     | p3    |50|40|50     
2     | p1    |80|40|50     
2     | p2    |20|90|50     
3     | p1    |10|80|50     
3     | p2    |20|0|50
```

Each parcel has packets and each packet has a, b and c buildings. The objective is to capture the packets that comprise the set proporation (e.g 80%) of the total buildings within each parcel. For example, the total of all buildings in parcel 3 is 50+20+10+80+50=210; 80% of 210 is 168. So, we need packet 1 (140) + packet 2 (70) to achieve 80%.

I am currently trying to get the sums done for each of the packets manually, and then compute the proportions manually. I know there is a better way to achieve this in R. I have used dplyr, sqldf and other R functions but this is little steep for me. Help appreciated.

Comment: I don't seem to understand what do you mean by "we need packet1 and packet2 to achieve it". However, I've started with an answer, and can edit it with updates.

Comment: Thanks. The idea is to identify and separate the packets within each parcel that would give us a total of 80%. You have certainly suggested something very useful. In the example, I wanted to illustrate that in parcel 3, packets 1 and 2 are required to hit  >80% of the total value. The final objective is to come out with the rows containing the parcel and respective packets that total to 80% or more. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are looking for, using the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(parcel = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3),
                 packet = c("p1","p2","p3","p1","p2","p1","p2"), 
                 a = c(20,20,50,80,20,10,20),
                 b = c(40,90,40,40,90,80,0),
                 c = c(50,50,50,50,50,50,50))

dt[,total:= a+b+c,][,group:= sum(total)*.80,by = parcel]
dt
#    parcel packet  a  b  c total  group
# 1:      1     p1 20 40 50   110 328
# 2:      1     p2 20 90 50   160 328
# 3:      1     p3 50 40 50   140 328
# 4:      2     p1 80 40 50   170 264
```

Comment: Thanks Arun. I was able to calculate the total packet sum and the group sum based on your method using R, data.table. I can proceed to identifying the packets now.